# python unicode to str exception

Tags: python, string, unicode, type-conversion

I am trying to convert this unicode: `u"\u2605 adasdadad"` to `str` and got this exception:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2605' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Help please.

Comment: That is a black star, if you `print  u"\u2605 adasdadad"` you will see it. What do you want to do with it?

Answer (score 3):

```
u"\u2605 adasdadad".encode("utf8")
```

perhaps

Comment: thanks ... think mbatteries on my keyboard are dying